# How to turn a Ceylon class which extends a Java class into the Java class

Tags: ceylon

Suppose you have a Java method in a legacy library you need to use that takes a Class as an argument:

```
public void takeClass(Class<? extends JavaClass> cls);
```

Now, suppose you have a Ceylon class which extends JavaClass:

```
shared class CeylonClass() extends JavaClass() {}
```

Now, how can I use the method `takeClass` in Ceylon such that this works?

```
javaThing.takeClass( `class CeylonClass` );

// or maybe this should work?
javaThing.takeClass( javaClass<CeylonClass>() );
```

As shown above, I've been trying function `javaClass` in module `ceylon.interop.java` without success... if I do `javaClass<JavaClass>()` then it works, but this is no use for me, of course.

**EDIT:**

The error I get when using `javaClass<CeylonClass>()` as shown above:

```
argument must be assignable to parameter class of takeClass:
Class<CeylonClass> is not assignable to Class<JavaClass>?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a case where you need to drop back to Java to add some glue. You can't, today, write it completely in Ceylon.

### Explanation

The problem is that since Ceylon doesn't have use-site covariance, and since the Ceylon typechecker doesn't even understand *Java*'s use-site covariance, the typechecker treats this method:

```
public void takeClass(Class<? extends JavaClass> cls);
```

As if it had this more restrictive signature:

```
public void takeClass(Class<JavaClass> cls);
```

Furthermore, the typechecker treats all Java classes as if they were invariant types.

Therefore, since `javaClass<CeylonClass>()` produces a `Class<CeylonClass>`, it's not considered assignable to the parameter of `takeClass()`. :-(

### Workaround

The workaround is to add the following Java method:

```
public static <T extends JavaClass> void takeClass2(Class<T> cls) {
    takeClass(cls);
}
```

Now this method *can* be called like this from Ceylon:

```
javaThing.takeClass2( javaClass<CeylonClass>() );
```

HTH

### P.S.

While writing this up, I noticed that in fact `java.lang.Class` is *actually* a covariant type, and I think that Ceylon should easily be able to notice that too. So I created this issue:

https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon-compiler/issues/1474

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.